# Make an Oracle foreign key constraint referencing USER_SEQUENCES(SEQUENCE_NAME)?

Tags: oracle

I want to create a table with a column that references the name of a sequence I've also created.  Ideally, I'd like to have a foreign key constraint that enforces this.  I've tried

```
create table testtable (
  sequence_name varchar2(128),
  constraint testtableconstr
    foreign key (sequence_name)
    references user_sequences (sequence_name)
    on delete set null
);
```

but I'm getting a `SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.  I suspect either this just isn't possible, or I need to add something like `on update cascade`.  What, if anything, can I do to enforce this constraint when I insert rows into this table?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing a FOREIGN KEY to metadata tables. It would bring XREF between your code and the database model. Not only that but USER_SEQUENCES is a synonym that points to a view. You would have to reference the underlying physical metadata table. However you could use INSERT/UPDATE triggers on your table to validate that the sequence exists in USER_SEQUENCES and throw an exeption if it doesn't on inserts and updates. Now what do you do with the "DROP SEQUENCE"...

Comment: @MarcoPolo What exactly do you mean by XREF between my code and the database model?  Dependent on there being a user_sequence synonym/view/table?

Comment: When you do "SELECT * FROM USER_SEQUENCES" you are really using a public synonym called "USER_SEQUENCES" that points to a view called "SYS.USER_SEQUENCES". That view uses SYS.SEQ$ and SYS.OBJ$ witch are Oracle internal tables. If you reference these tables directly you are now dependent on the Oracle version of your database. Future upgrades might screw up you model. Having a trigger detaches you from the physical Oracle table and is more elegant and safer.

Comment: @MarcoPolo Thanks--I had assumed the USER_SEQUENCES synonym would be guaranteed to exist in future upgrades.  Also, using triggers makes sense, though they are generally avoided at my workplace.

Comment: USER_SEQUENCES synonym is pretty much assured to be present in future release BUT to establish a FOREIGN KEY you would need to reference the underling physical table SYS.SEQ$ and that's the one that might change. In a trigger you would reference USER_SEQUENCES which will be there for a long time.

Comment: @MarcoPolo Ah, that makes more sense.  Good to know--thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to build some sort of deployment management system to keep track of your schema objects including sequences.

To do what you ask, you might explore one of the following options:

1. Run a report after each deployment that compares the values in your table vs. the data dictionary view, and lists any discrepancies.
2. Create a DDL trigger which does the insert automatically whenever a sequence is created.
3. Add a trigger to the table which does a query on the sequences view and raises an exception if not found.

Comment: You have to understand what a sequence is and it's typical use case. Typically you use it to great a unique number, to be used as s primary key. You access it via <sequence_names>.nextval   You can then use the sequence for foreign keys, via <sequence_name>.currval

Comment: Hi BobC, that's right but that's not really what we're talking about here - this could be any schema object, not just a sequence.

Comment: Option three is what applies in my case.  I'm actually using different sequences to generate subaccount numbers for different accounts.  There's probably a better way, but it seems easier than dealing with locks directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat confused at what you are trying to achieve here - a sequence (effectively) only has a single value, the next number to be allocated, not all the values that have been previously allocated.

If you simply want to ensure that an attribute in the relation is populated from the sequence, then a trigger would be the right approach.

Comment: I want to be able to reference sequence names in my table.  I want to be able to do `create sequence seqA; create sequence seqB; insert into testtable(sequence_name) values ('SEQA'); insert into testtable (sequence_name)  values ('SEQB')`, but then have an error when I try to do `insert into testtable(sequence_name) values ('SEQC');`, assuming sequence `SEQC` hasn't been created.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help me understand what you want.

Comment: @BenjaminBerman  Why not try an explain logically (as opposed to describing an implementation), what you are trying to achieve.